# could not connect to development server react native android studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I reinstall node modules again and this error appears

`Error: Forward-slash in opening tag not followed by >Line: 9Column: 42Char: /    at error (F:\project\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:651:10)    at strictFail (F:\project\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:677:7)    at SAXParser.write (F:\project\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1295:13)    at new XmlDocument (F:\project\node_modules\xmldoc\lib\xmldoc.js:261:15)    at readManifest (F:\project\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\config\readManifest.js:38:10)    at Object.projectConfig (F:\project\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\config\index.js:70:46)    at Object.get project [as project] (F:\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js:106:50)    at filterConfig (F:\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\config\config.js:13:20)    at Object.func (F:\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\config\config.js:27:32)    at Command.handleAction (F:\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:23)`

Comment: Was it working before re-installation?

Comment: NO, it's not worked

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in your AndroidManifest.xml.